# trying to connect this menu with this data, in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a class = "dot" situation = "LA">managua</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "AA" >japon</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "GO" >goa</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "MA" >madrid</a><br />
<br />
<form id="mapForm" name="mapForm" method="post" action="" class="formCities">
   <select name="cities" id="cities">
          <option value="AA">japon</option>
          <option value="MA">madrid</option>
          <option value="LA">managua</option>
          <option value="GO">goa</option>
          <option value="cities" selected = "selected">cities</option>
    </select>
</form> <br />


<h2 id = "otherMenu" class = "menu_class" >My menu </h2>
<ul class="the_menu">
<li><a href="#" value="AA">japon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" value="MA">madrid</a></li>
<li><a href="#" value="LA">managua</a></li>
<li><a href="#" value="GO">goa</a></li>
</ul>


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

$(document).ready(function(){

$('h2.menu_class').click(function () {
    $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');

});
    //This works
    /*

    $('#mapForm').change(function() {

        var selectedCity = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
        alert(selectedCity);
        if (selectedCity == 'cities'){
            $('a.dot').show(1000);
    }else{

        $('a.dot[situation *= "'+selectedCity+'"]').show(1000);
        $('a.dot[situation != "'+selectedCity+'"]').hide(1000);

        }
      */
        // but not this way? why???

          $('#otherMenu ').change(function() {

        var selectedCity = $('#otherMenu a:onclick').val(); // I guess here it's the problem
              alert(selectedCity );
        if (selectedCity == 'cities'){
            $('a.dot').show(1000);
    }else{

        $('a.dot[situation *= "'+selectedCity+'"]').show(1000);
        $('a.dot[situation != "'+selectedCity+'"]').hide(1000);

        }


 });
```

Hi gurls and boys I'm learning jquery.Im trying present this data( list of the countries) interacting with different menus. :( The selection form runs good but the "menu-list " cant make it work :(

Thanks for help :(

Have a look at my work: http://jsfiddle.net/yoniGeek/JNfm4/1/

Comment: Chat do you want to do exactly with this menu ? You want to show/hide the items inside ? (I did not knew this website, really handy tool).

Comment: @schmurfy yes exactly!show/hide the items using the secong jquery-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Items I changed.:

1. Id's must be unique. Therefore, `<h2 id="mapForm">` became `<h2 id="mapForm-2">` Note, while nominal and not changed, style generally dictates that there should be no spaces between attributes and the values. notice `<h2 id="mapForm-2">` not `<h2 id = "mapForm-2">`
2. I separated the functions. You may want to consider abstracting the functions together, but this seemed    to be the most pragmatic solution at the time. Consider the other homework?
3. the variable selectedCity in the
      second function grabs a class and
      not a val. This also meant I needed
      to give the bottom menu a class.
      Your original live example had
      neither class or value. I tried
      using .val(), but it was not working
      as expected. I am sure there is a
      valid reason for this. The
      [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) api suggests it should
      be used primarily for forms
4. removed the conditional clause in the second menu function. There was no 'cities' option. As a result it was unnecessary. Perhaps you want to consider adding this as a menu selection.
5. changed the second menu function to a [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and not a [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) The latter is designed to be used on a `<select>` and this is being called obviously on a link.

---

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/kgRRu/

---

As a result I believe the following is what you are after:

**HTML**

```
<a class = "dot" situation = "LA" city = "Mikayo" alt = "Mikayo">managua</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "AA" city = "Mikayo" alt = "Mikayo">japon</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "GO" city = "Mikayo" alt = "Mikayo">goa</a><br />
<a class = "dot" situation = "MA" city = "Mikayo" alt = "Mikayo">madrid</a><br />
<br />
<form id="mapForm" name="mapForm" method="post" action="" class="formCities">
    <select name="cities" id="cities">
        <option value="AA">japon</option>
        <option value="MA">madrid</option>
        <option value="LA">managua</option>
        <option value="GO">goa</option>
        <option value="cities" selected = "selected">cities</option>
    </select>
</form> <br />


<h2 id = "mapForm-2" class = "menu_class" >My menu </h2>
<ul class="the_menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="AA">japon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="MA">madrid</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="LA">managua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="GO">goa</a></li>
</ul>
```

**javascripit**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('h2.menu_class').click(function() {
        $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');

    });



    $('#mapForm').change(function() {

        var selectedCity = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
        if (selectedCity == 'cities') {
            $('a.dot').show(1000);
        } else {

            $('a.dot[situation *= "' + selectedCity + '"]').show(1000);
            $('a.dot[situation != "' + selectedCity + '"]').hide(1000);

        }

    });


    $('ul.the_menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedCity = $(this).attr('class');

        $('a.dot[situation *= "' + selectedCity + '"]').show(1000);
        $('a.dot[situation != "' + selectedCity + '"]').hide(1000);


    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event is only supported by form elements, such as `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`. Similarly, `value` and `situation` are not valid attributes on `<a>` tags, please avoid using them.

To do what you want, you have to bind a function to the `click` event to the anchors within your menu items. Custom values can be stored in custom data attributes, which can be retrieved by jQuery's `.data()` method. The ideal replacement for your `situation` attribute would be to use custom classes. It would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="dot city-LA">managua</a><br />
<a class="dot city-AA">japon</a><br />
<a class="dot city-GO">goa</a><br />
<a class="dot city-MA">madrid</a><br />

<h2 id="otherMenu" class="menu_class">My menu</h2>
<ul class="the_menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="AA">japon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="MA">madrid</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="LA">managua</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="GO">goa</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.the_menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedCity = $(this).data('value');

    if (selectedCity == 'cities') {
        $('a.dot').show(1000);
    } else {
        $('a.dot.city-' + selectedCity).show(1000);
        $('a.dot.city-' + selectedCity).hide(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there!  how do u know that change-event works just with <lements>, <forms>:  I mean do I need to read the jquery API do u have any way to learn this? or u just look at the API everytime u want to know how things work with the framework? thanks

Comment: This is not linked with jquery but javascript itself, only elements which can actually change trigger this event. Just by messing around you should quickly catch things, just be careful with browsers compatibility: different browsers (ie ?) may do things differently.

Comment: @YoniGeek jQuery is a very useful library, but it does not save you the time to learn Javascript and HTML correctly.